# Body background image causes the FPS to drop in safari for iPad

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, mobile-safari, background-image

I have a website with a jquery cycle slideshow. It slides smoothly on the ipad, but if i add a css background image to the body, it seems like the FPS drops and the slide effect looks really bad. This happends even if the background image is smaller than the iPad screen.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use hardware acceleration like adding the `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` CSS to the block you want to accelerate.

Here is a good [article about GPU accelerating](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/#toc-hardware-accell).

Also, I don't know what image do you use, but there is a bug in webkits, where using CSS3 radial gradients for background may cause great drops in FPS.